Uncaught TypeError when adding OpenLayers Measure tool to App
I am trying to add the Measure tool from Examples to my map application and keep getting the following error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getLayers')
at parcelRequire.Scripts/customFunctions.js (extent.js:922:1)
at newRequire (dom.js:34:23)
at localRequire (proj.js:62:1)
at parcelRequire.Scripts/Identify.js.ol/Overlay.js (extent.js:922:1)
at newRequire (dom.js:34:23)
at has.js:86:7
at epsg3857.js:105:3

My customFunctions.js script isn't called in the Measure.js script and worked fine before adding the Measure tool code. Its simple and the code looks like this:
const map = $('#map').data('map');
const mapLayers = map.getLayers();

export function getLayerByName(layerName) {
    let layer = null;

    mapLayers.forEach(lyr => {
        if(lyr.get('name') === layerName) {
            layer=lyr;
        } 
    });
    return layer;
}

I have added the JavaScript code for the Measure tool in a Measure.js file and pull it in using a <script> tag in my index.html. The example can be found here. Here's the actual code below. Up until this point, everything was working in the application (map, layer list, identify tool). I am wondering if its a version issue, or the order in which I added the Measure.js script (Map.js, 'Indentify.js', 'Layers.js', 'Measure.js') or something else. Any suggestion?
import Draw from 'ol/interaction/Draw.js';
import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay.js';
import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style.js';
import {LineString, Polygon} from 'ol/geom.js';
import {Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source.js';
import {Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import {getArea, getLength} from 'ol/sphere.js';
import {unByKey} from 'ol/Observable.js';

const map = $('#map').data('map');
const source = new VectorSource();

const vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: source,
  style: {
    'fill-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
    'stroke-color': '#ffcc33',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    'circle-radius': 7,
    'circle-fill-color': '#ffcc33',
  },
});

/**
 * Currently drawn feature.
 * @type {import("../src/ol/Feature.js").default}
 */
let sketch;

/**
 * The help tooltip element.
 * @type {HTMLElement}
 */
let helpTooltipElement;

/**
 * Overlay to show the help messages.
 * @type {Overlay}
 */
let helpTooltip;

/**
 * The measure tooltip element.
 * @type {HTMLElement}
 */
let measureTooltipElement;

/**
 * Overlay to show the measurement.
 * @type {Overlay}
 */
let measureTooltip;

/**
 * Message to show when the user is drawing a polygon.
 * @type {string}
 */
const continuePolygonMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the polygon';

/**
 * Message to show when the user is drawing a line.
 * @type {string}
 */
const continueLineMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the line';

/**
 * Handle pointer move.
 * @param {import("../src/ol/MapBrowserEvent").default} evt The event.
 */
const pointerMoveHandler = function (evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  /** @type {string} */
  let helpMsg = 'Click to start drawing';

  if (sketch) {
    const geom = sketch.getGeometry();
    if (geom instanceof Polygon) {
      helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
    } else if (geom instanceof LineString) {
      helpMsg = continueLineMsg;
    }
  }

  helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
  helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);

  helpTooltipElement.classList.remove('hidden');
};

map.addLayer(vector);

map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);

map.getViewport().addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
  helpTooltipElement.classList.add('hidden');
});

const typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

let draw; // global so we can remove it later

/**
 * Format length output.
 * @param {LineString} line The line.
 * @return {string} The formatted length.
 */
const formatLength = function (line) {
  const length = getLength(line);
  let output;
  if (length > 100) {
    output = Math.round((length / 1000) * 100) / 100 + ' ' + 'km';
  } else {
    output = Math.round(length * 100) / 100 + ' ' + 'm';
  }
  return output;
};

/**
 * Format area output.
 * @param {Polygon} polygon The polygon.
 * @return {string} Formatted area.
 */
const formatArea = function (polygon) {
  const area = getArea(polygon);
  let output;
  if (area > 10000) {
    output = Math.round((area / 1000000) * 100) / 100 + ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
  } else {
    output = Math.round(area * 100) / 100 + ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
  }
  return output;
};

const style = new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    lineDash: [10, 10],
    width: 2,
  }),
  image: new CircleStyle({
    radius: 5,
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
    }),
  }),
});

function addInteraction() {
  const type = typeSelect.value == 'area' ? 'Polygon' : 'LineString';
  draw = new Draw({
    source: source,
    type: type,
    style: function (feature) {
      const geometryType = feature.getGeometry().getType();
      if (geometryType === type || geometryType === 'Point') {
        return style;
      }
    },
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);

  createMeasureTooltip();
  createHelpTooltip();

  let listener;
  draw.on('drawstart', function (evt) {
    // set sketch
    sketch = evt.feature;

    /** @type {import("../src/ol/coordinate.js").Coordinate|undefined} */
    let tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

    listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function (evt) {
      const geom = evt.target;
      let output;
      if (geom instanceof Polygon) {
        output = formatArea(geom);
        tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
      } else if (geom instanceof LineString) {
        output = formatLength(geom);
        tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
      }
      measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
      measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
    });
  });

  draw.on('drawend', function () {
    measureTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-static';
    measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
    // unset sketch
    sketch = null;
    // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
    measureTooltipElement = null;
    createMeasureTooltip();
    unByKey(listener);
  });
}

/**
 * Creates a new help tooltip
 */
function createHelpTooltip() {
  if (helpTooltipElement) {
    helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElement);
  }
  helpTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  helpTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip hidden';
  helpTooltip = new Overlay({
    element: helpTooltipElement,
    offset: [15, 0],
    positioning: 'center-left',
  });
  map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
}

/**
 * Creates a new measure tooltip
 */
function createMeasureTooltip() {
  if (measureTooltipElement) {
    measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
  }
  measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltip = new Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center',
    stopEvent: false,
    insertFirst: false,
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
}

/**
 * Let user change the geometry type.
 */
typeSelect.onchange = function () {
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
  addInteraction();
};

addInteraction();


You are expecting $('#map').data('map') to be an OpenLayers map object but it returns undefined.  You need to show how you are creating your map.
